# Faster XML File reading than xsd generated classes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, performance

I am processing lots and lots of XML files that contain HL7 Info.

The structure of these XML files is described in several complex XSD files.  They are a hierarchy of XSD files. like this:

- Messages.xsd

  - batch.xsd
  - datatypes.xsd

    - Fields.xsd
  - MoreFiles.xsd

    - Fields.xsd

That is not the exact usage, but it helps convey the idea of how they work.

Now I can run

> xsd .\messages.xsd /classes

and it generates a file called messages.cs file that is over 240,000 lines long.

**Note:** Despite the complexity of the XSD, the actual xml files average around 250 lines of XML with about 25 chars per line (Not really huge).

I can use that file to deserialize my xml files like this:

```
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.Message);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var message = ormSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
```

That all works great and fast.

When it comes time to pull the data out of the xml structure it is **too slow**.

Is there another way to access my xml data that would be faster?  Should I use `XPathDocument` and `XPathNavigator`?  Can `XPathNavigator` use all the XSD files so I don't have to re-create it for each xml file I process (Not all XML Nodes are in all XML Files)?

Any other ideas to get XML Data out fast?

Comment: Maybe re-think the getting data out part.  Why not have your code use the XML in place?  In other words, stop serializing XML into member variables, and just have your classes operate directly on in-memory XML documents and elements.  Good luck, have a good w/e.

Comment: I'm confused - you say the Deserialize is fast, then say accessing values is too slow... Which is it? What am I missing?

Comment: @Marc - it is weird.  But the call to deserialize goes fast. But the calls to the object structure that it fills are slow.  (The object structure is what is made by the XSD command line tool.  (Messages.cs))

Comment: once deserialized, that should be a flat class model; do you have an example of a "slow" query?

Comment: @Marc - There is not one that is supper slow.  I just have a lot of reading to do and it goes slower than I would like.  an Example of me getting data out would look like this:  try { MyValue = contract.ORM_O01PATIENT.PID.PID3[0].CX1.Value; } catch (NullReferenceException) { }

Comment: @Marc - I do about 16 of those in one class and it is taking 1/4 a second (262 ms).  Not too long usually, but I have 4 similar classes to run in order to process one message.  And I have ton of messages to process.  I am hoping I can speed it up some how.

Comment: NOTE: Deserialization takes about 3 ms.  Is it possible that the call to Deserialze is using deferred execution?

Comment: @Vaccano Deferred deserialization isn't possible with XmlSerializer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "When it comes time to pull the data out of the xml structure it is too slow." Can you post some code showing exactly where this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology you are using (automatic mapping of XML to Java or C# classes) is called "data binding" and it works beautifully when the schema is simple and small. For something as big and ugly as HL7, I would have said it is a non-starter.

What kind of processing are you doing? Is there any good reason why you can't do it in XSLT or XQuery? These languages are designed to process XML and they avoid the "impedence mismatch" that you get when you have to convert data from the XML model to the data model of a programming language such as Java or C#.

Comment: I am just pulling out select values from the XML file. I confess I do not usually work with parsing XML. I will look into xquery and see if it will work better / faster than what I am doing.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'd call that deserialization. Data-binding more commonly refers to UI binding etc. and the OP reports that isn't excessively slow:

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like XStreamingReader?  It allowes you to use Linq to XML while streaming over large XML documents.  I looked at this in the past and was able to stream over XML, identify chunks of XML and deserialize them into objects.  If you mess with this and need examples, I can dig up the code.

http://xstreamingreader.codeplex.com/